# How does iOS decide between DHCPv4 and DHCPv6

Tags: network, ipv6

If I understood correctly, when a device connects to a network (wireless in my case), it will send both a DHCPv4 and DHCPv6 (if supported).

I've setup openwrt on my router in order to view the DHCP requests (with wireshark).

I have that windows clients consistently send both DHCP and DHCPv6 requests, but it looks like iPhones (iOS 14) never do. (DHCPv6 is not supported on Android, it seems)

Now, my router doesn't have a DHCPv6 sever, but I assumed it doesn't matter because I'm not interested in the station actually acquiring an address, I just want to see the request.

How does an iOS device decide whether to send a DHCPv6 request, and how can I force it to do so?

Does the iOS device somehow know that there's no DHCPv6 server before sending a request?

Comment: I *believe* that a DHCP request is sent to determine what is available via DHCP and if the server does not support IPV6 it will not request it. It *sounds* like Windows is sending those requests regardless.

Comment: IPv6 autoconfig should be telling clients on that network link whether or not there is a DHCPd they should be talking to.  It's not "link comes up, send a request".  That doesn't stop a client from DOING it, but you'll probably note the iOS devices have an autoconfig address even though they never sent a request.  https://www.ictshore.com/free-ccna-course/dhcpv6-basics/